# (discord.js) Check if bot has permissions doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots, typeerror

Many people have said to use `message.member.guild.me.hasPermission("PERMISSION") {`
to check if the bot has a permission. It used to work, but for some reason it stopped working which is really confusing to me because I am a new coder.

Edit - Here is my full code for more context:

```
module.exports = {
    name: "help",
    description: "Displays an embed with all the commands of the bot.",
    execute(client, message, args, Discord, msgAuthor) {
        const channel = message;
        
        if (message.member.guild.me.hasPermission("EMBED_LINKS" || "ADMINISTRATOR")) {
            if (!args[0]) {
                const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setColor('000000')
                    .setTitle('Esando Bot commands')
                    .setDescription('Remember to use the prefix at the start of any command!')
                    .addFields(
                        { name: 'help music', value: "Displays an embed for help regarding music." },
                        { name: 'invite', value: "Sends the invite link to the Esando Community server." },
                        { name: 'kick [@member]', value: 'Kicks a specified member from the server.' },
                        { name: 'ban [@member]', value: 'Bans a specified member from the server.' },
                        { name: 'slowmode [seconds]', value: "Sets the channels slowmode cooldown. You can use 'slowmode off' to turn off slowmode." },
                    )
                    .setFooter("Esando Bot", "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/786845863787626517/791421970200657940/bot3.png")

                message.channel.send(newEmbed);
            } else if (args[0] == 'music') {
                const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setColor('000000')
                    .setTitle('Esando Bot music commands')
                    .setDescription('Remember to use the prefix at the start of any command!')
                    .addFields(
                        { name: 'play [video name]', value: "Searches YouTube for that video and plays the first search result as audio. (You can also use URL's)" },
                        { name: 'leave', value: "Disconnects the bot from the voice channel (you must be in the same voice channel to execute this command)." },
                    )
                    .setFooter("Esando Bot", "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/786845863787626517/791421970200657940/bot3.png")

                message.channel.send(newEmbed);
            }
        } else {
            message.channel.send(`${msgAuthor} I don't have sufficient permissions to send embeds in ${channel}! To change this, make sure me or my role have the 'Embed Links' permission for this channel.`);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `message.member.guild` while the correct syntax would be `message.guild.member`

Comment: I now get this error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'member' of undefined

Comment: @Esando Can you edit your message and add all of your code from the file where the error is? I need more context

Comment: Done! Hope this helps!

Comment: @Esando it's best to not edit your question to say "I solved it", instead have your original question and leave your solution in the answers. You should do this so that other people that are having the same problem can see your solution

Comment: alright the solution is that in my 'execute(message, args, Discord)' I didn't have the same constants in the file with the "if (command === 'cmd') {" if you know what i mean.